# How to Access formData values in Controller class

Tags: java, jquery, spring

I am saving multiple rows in database,So i am passing values in ajax call in jquery.

```
$("button#submitbutton").click(function() {
 var data = [];
 var name, email, message;
 $("table tbody tr").each(function(index) {
name = $(this).find('.name').text();
email = $(this).find('.email').text();
message = $(this).find('.message').text();
//---->Form validation goes here
data.push({
  name: name,
  email: email,
  message: message
});
 });
 submitFormData(data);
});    
function submitFormData(formData) {
var url= '/userrecords';
alert(url);
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
        url: url,
        success: function(result){
        if(result.success == true) {
          $('.alert-success').show();
          $('.alert-danger').hide();
          $("#successmsg").html(result.msg);
          setTimeout(function() {
            $(".alert-success").alert('close');
          }, 10000);
        } else {
          $('.alert-danger').show();
          $('.alert-success').hide();
          $("#error").html(result.msg);
          setTimeout(function() {
            $(".alert-danger").alert('close');
          }, 10000);
        }
        }
});
}
```

In spring MVC i write controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userrecords")
public @ResponseBody Response saveList(Model model)
throws ParseException, SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException {
//read all values here
}
```

in controller class how to access formData values. i didn't get any idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    client side:

    data: {model:formData.serialize()},
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false

    server side:1.> your api method should have the 
    same model structure 
    2.> then deserialize your model 
    3.> name of the object also be same like : model here

    @RequestMapping(value = "/userrecords")
    public @ResponseBody Response saveList(Model model)
    throws ParseException, SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException {
    //read all values here
    }
```

Comment: server side i have POJO class in that class setters and getters implemented.

Comment: 'TypeError: formData.serialize is not a function'

Comment: @user7646838 you have used array `var data = [];` it'll not serialize you need to add `FormData` instead please [read this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

Comment: yes sory for that,serialize will work on forms,you can use JSON.stringify(your array)

Answer (score 0):

Need to correct below points

1. Decorate method with `POST` like `@RequestMapping(value = "/userrecords,method=RequestMethod.POST")`
2. Serialize your form data while parsing to ajax request [.serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)
3. Make sure your `Model` class have **name,email and message** with same structure

Comment: put a debug point on action method in controller and check your `Model` class is getting value or not?

Answer (score 0):

- Create dto model (lombok + you can use @NotNull @Size(min=1) instead @NotEmpty and implement your own annotation and validator for valid email if you don't want hibernate dependency)

  ```
  @Data
  @AllArgsConstructor
  @NoArgsConstructor
  public class DataModel {

      @NotEmpty
      private String name;

      @Email
      private String email;

      @NotEmpty
      private String message;
  }
  ```
- In your controller produces/consumes specify type of request/response body and valid annotation triggers field validation in deserialized model.

  ```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/userrecords", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
                  consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE } )
  @ResponseBody
  public Response saveList(@Valid @RequestBody DataModel data, BindingResult result, Model data)
         throws ParseException, SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException {
        //read all values here
  }
  ```

Comment: i am getting [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: i created pojo class in java.but values not possible to access. property names are same in javascript file and pojo class

Comment: Did you add lombok annotations or getter/setters and empty/all constructor

Comment: No,just i added **consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }** in @RequestMapping but it not entered in controller class.

Comment: I asked did you added getters and setters in pojo DataModel class? Do it.